# Linq to SQL slow with ForEach

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I been asked to speed up the performance of a very long query (only a portion of it is listed here but it will give the general idea of what's going on).  I believe that the numerous for each statements (about 10) are causing this to drag on forever.  This is resulting in the browser message "script taking too long".  Even when this isn't the case it is taking a very long time to run.

My question is this.  Isn't there a better way to do this????

Here is the code.

```
var query = questions
   .Where(x => !x.IsExcluded)
   .OrderBy(x => x.PrimaryOrder)
   .ThenBy(x => x.SecondaryOrder)
   .GroupBy(x => x.Id);

foreach (var q in query)
{
    var edits = new List<QuestionEdit>();
    var answers = new List<ResponseEntity>();

    foreach (var r in responses.
      Where(x => x.OpportunityContactInterviewQuestionId == q.First().Id))
    {
        answers.Add(new ResponseEntity()
        {
            PrimaryAnswerValue = r.PrimaryAnswerValue,
            PrimaryAnswerText = r.PrimaryAnswerText,
            SecondaryAnswerValue = r.SecondaryAnswerValue,
            SecondaryAnswerText = r.SecondaryAnswerText,
            IsOther = r.IsOther,
            OtherValue = r.OtherValue,
            LoopInstance = r.LoopInstance,
            LoopText = r.LoopText,
            IsSelected = r.IsSelected,
            LowValue = r.LowValue,
            HighValue = r.HighValue
        });
    }
....
```

Comment: Are you really working with `linq-to-sql`, `linq-to-entities` and `linq-to-objects` at the same time?

Comment: Looks like that.  I am having to unwind this code.  But yes, there are all of the above.

Comment: If you have enough memory, cache the remote data locally in order to save network time.

Comment: You may need to post more code. From this it looks like q is only used to get the Ids from questions, which could be done with a select instead of a groupby. Then you could also combine the queries

Comment: Get a profiler to see what SQL is actually executed. There might be a N+1 problem. If so, read up on LoadWidth for L2S.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to direct your attention to `.GroupBy(x => x.Id);`

GroupBy is *usually* very inefficient in LinqTo something, as it works different than the sql `group by`command.

What you end up with is an IGrouping and depending on how you access that IGrouping you often trigger a new SELECT to get all the rows in the IGrouping.

In your example, you are only using the Key (Id) of the IGrouping, I am sure you in the omitted code uses more information. But if you are only using the key of the IGrouping there are other ways to get to that data. Either by selecting the Id and then using Distinct (with no GroupBy) or by using GroupBy followed by a `.Select(v => v.Key)`.

Also, you "need" to control when your queries are realised by using for instance `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` at the proper time. If you do not, you might end up with the same query executing multiple times.

And as Pleun said in the comments, use a profiler. Or just download LINQPad and play with your queries there. LINQPad is an invaluable tool (and if you do not need autocomplete, it is free).